# C# Generic with class constraint

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I am studying C# and generics with class constraint like

```
public class GenericList<T> where T : Employee
```

I am puzzled because I see nothing generic here. The GenericList list is bound to the Employee's class. It would be same as if we inject Employee from the GenericList's constructor.

Or I am missing something?

Comment: `T` could be `Employee` as well as any descendents of `Employee`.  if `Employee` was sealed, then yes, you could not really provide anything for `T` _except_ `Employee`. though theoretically in the future the class could be unsealed and inherited from and then those child classes could be used also.

Comment: I see the `<T>` was hidden by the lack of formatting

Comment: Thank you. That lack of formatting was copy paste issue.
When we inject we can inject descendants of the Employee too. Not sure if we can inject them directly or through an interface.

Like

public class GenericList(IEmploee emp)

Comment: It's also worth noting that an unconstrained generic, like `public class MyClass<T>`, is the same as `public class MyClass<T> where T : object`. So by definition, it's generic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I see nothing generic here

That's what the `<T>` is after the name of the type (`GenericList`). `T` is the name of the generic parameter.

> The GenericList list is bound to the Employee's class.

`T` can be an `Employee`, or it can be any type that inherits `Employee`, either directly or through another type.

> It would be same as if we inject Employee from the GenericList's constructor.

Not really. What you do in the constructor really has nothing to do with the generic parameter. Generics allow you to modify the type. For example, you can have these different variables.

```
GenericList<Employee> a;
GenericList<FullTimeEmployee> b;
GenericList<PartTimeEmployee> c;
```

These are all different types.

Dependency injection just works with parameters in the type's constructor. Yes, those parameter can include types that have generic arguments (for example, you can ask for an `ILogger<MyService>`), but they `T` type you specify doesn't really have a parallel otherwise.

Comment: Thank you. When we inject we can inject descendants of the Employee too. Not sure if we can inject them directly or through an interface.

Like

public class GenericList(IEmployee emp)

Comment: Sure, if you register a `GenericList<Employee>` in your DI provider, you can request a `GenericList<Employee>` in another service's constructor. Same with a `GenericList<FullTimeEmployee>`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

> I am puzzled because I see nothing generic here. The GenericList list is bound to the Employee's class.

I agree that it is a bit hard to see the point of the generic type parameter seeing only a part of class declaration here. But imagine 2 following things:

1. `Employee` is a part of type hierarchy and has descendants (`Boss : Employee`, `MegaBoss : Boss`)
2. `GenericList` has methods like `Add` and `Get`.

Without generic parameterization it could look something like:

```
public class NotActuallyGenericList
{
    public void Add(Employee employee) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public Employee Get(int index) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

which could be used as:

```
var list = new NotActuallyGenericList();
list.Add(new Employee());
Employee e = list.Get(0);
```

Now imagine you need to create a list which should contain only bosses (i.e. instances of `Boss` type), then:

```
var onlyBossesList = new NotActuallyGenericList();
onlyBossesList.Add(new Boss()); 
Boss e = (Boss)onlyBossesList.Get(1); // neither very convenient nor type-safe 
onlyBossesList.Add(new Employee()); // not type-safe
```

While the generic list will be totally fine:

```
var onlyBossesList = new GenericEmployeeList<Boss>();
onlyBossesList.Add(new Boss()); 
Boss b = onlyBossesList.Get(1); 
// onlyBossesList.Add(new Employee()); // will not compile

public class GenericEmployeeList<T> where T : Employee
{
    public void Add(T employee) => throw new NotImplementedException(); 
    public T Get(int index) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

And adding the constraint will allow to use `Employee`-specific methods/properties inside the `GenericEmployeeList` (for example use id to build index for `GetById`, etc.).

So (see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics#generics-overview) for generic goals), in this case generics allow to achieve code reuse and type safety.

Comment: Thank you first of all.
I was saying that we can not sent say Vehicle class instead of Employee. 
And we can achieve exactly the same through DI if we inject IEmployee employee. Then we can inject Employee, Boss, etc., for a s long as they implement IEmployee interface. Or inherit from a class which implements it.

Comment: @ILIIACHTEREV was glad to help! Yes, using interfaces would be usually preferable in such cases.